# server performance metrics report and practicality

Tags: web-server, reporting, metrics

I have a need of preparing web server (apache-php) performance report containing important metrics like CPU usage, disk io, memory usage on user basis. Couple of domains are hosted in the same server and they run from separate users using fcgi. The reason being sometimes some hosted applications take lots of cpu usage, making the server slow for other applications (running as separate users).

i am planning to develop scripts for this, as i can't seem to find any simple utilities for this purpose. This script will take snapshots of the user wise metrics at defined periods say 15 minutes and record it. Any abnormalities will be reported via emails. 
How practical is that? also would be interesting to know what else need to be recorded.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to reinvent the wheel IMHO. There are many applications that do this for you. I'd recommend [Nagios](http://nagios.org/), which is the standard for monitoring. Other interesting applications are [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) and [Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.com/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had looked at Nagios before. But I couldn't find userwise performance measurements in it. I will see whether others you recommend, fulfills my requirements or not. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at Munin:

http://munin-monitoring.org/